# Application was working in Firefox 52 but in Firefox 61 it gets freeze showing error

Tags: firefox, mozilla, firefox-quantum

Whenever I am running my application in the latest Firefox Quantum 61 browser it gets frozen and I am receiving this message on a yellow line:

> A WEB PAGE IS SLOWING DOWN YOUR BROWSER. WHAT WOULD YOU LIKE TO DO?

The same application is working fine in Firefox 51, Chrome and IE. Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Did you try debugging it?

Comment: I am seeing this on many and varied web pages using Firefox.  Searching for a solution brought me here.  So it may well be a Mozilla thing.